# Apply Friendly URL to Sub Site Default URL

Tags: url, sub-site, managed-navigation, global-navigation, term-set

**How can I apply a friendly-url to the default sub-site url?**

(ie: http://site/subsite/)

I am able to apply a friendly-url to the sub-site default page.

(ie: http://site/subsite/default.aspx)

I have a managed navigation using terms and friendly-urls. 
These terms are linking to a sub-site homepage or default page.

However, the sub-site default URL does not function the same as the default.aspx page.

Also search results display the default URL not the friendly URL. **NOTE**: I have turned on "Hide Physical URL" on the default.aspx pages.

**The global navigation is:**

- Teams | Forms | Resources | Manuals | Contacts

**The Department term-set is:**

- Departments > Teams > Team A (sub-site)
- Departments > Teams > Team B (sub-site)
- Departments > Teams > Team C (sub-site)

**The physical pages are:**

- http://site/subsite
- http://site/subsite/Pages/default.aspx

**The friendly-urls are:**

- http://site/teams/subsite

Answer (score 0):

It came to me two possible solution:

1) Use the [re-write module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) in IIS and use regular expression.

2) If you are able to configure the reverse proxy , for example Netscaler, APPExpert, edit the [responder policy and action](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/11/appexpert/responder/responder-action-policy-examples.html) under and the bind to the Content swicth Virtual server.

**NOTE:**  There is a chance that you might mix both of them